# How to change one value in _$GET[] by clicking a link (or button) from Twig without changing other values?

Tags: php, twig, query-string

I have other search queries, like query from search, from tags etc. I don't want to change them. The pageno value will be used for pagination.

So I want to change 'pageno' without changing or taking off other.

This is what I did in Twig:

```
<a href=?{{ request.server.get('QUERY_STRING')|replace({"&pageno=" : ""}) }}&pageno={{ page }}>{{ page }}</a>
```

But it give a result like this: ?query=&from-date=&to-date=&search=search413&pageno=5

Collecting former page numbers "413" when you navigate from page to page, and it always adds a "&".

Another method I tried is to make a string in php, and pass it on the Twig template:

```
$queryStr = $request->server->get('QUERY_STRING');
$queryStr = preg_replace("/pageno=\\w+/", "", $queryStr); // Remove pageno=???
$queryStr = $queryStr == "" ? "" : ($queryStr . "&");  // ad a & if there's already other $_GET values
$queryStr = str_replace("&&","&", $queryStr); // replace && so it doesn't look bad
```

In Twig:

```
<a href=?{{ queryStr }}pageno={{ page }}>{{ page }}</a>
```

That looks too tricky too much work work done, and I'm passing a lot of values to Twig.

Is there a simpler way to do it without having to pass so many values to Twig?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `twig` function like this:

```php
$twig->addFunction(new \Twig\TwigFunction('get_page_url', function($query = [], $append = true) {
    $tmp = $append ? $_GET : [];
    foreach($query as $key => $value) $tmp[$key] = $value;

    return '?' . http_build_query($tmp);
});
```

Use it in `twig` like

```html
<a href="{{ get_page_url({ 'pageno': 42, }) }}">next</a>
```